# Python lxml error "namespace not defined."

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I am being driven crazy by some oddly formed xml and would be grateful for some pointers:

The documents are defined like this:

```
<sphinx:document id="18059090929806848187">
  <url>http://www.some-website.com</url>
  <page_number>104</page_number>
  <size>7865</size>
</sphinx:document>
```

Now, I need to read lots (500m+ of these files which are all gz compresed) and grab the text values form a few of the contained tags.

sample code:

```
from lxml import objectify, etree
import gzip

with open ('file_list','rb') as file_list:
 for file in file_list:
  in_xml = gzip.open(file.strip('\n'))
  xml2 = etree.iterparse(in_xml)
  for action, elem in xml2:
   if elem.tag == "page_number":
    print elem.text + str(file)
```

the first value elem.text is returned but only for the first file in the list and quickly followed by the error:

lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix sphinx on document is not defined, line 1, column 20

Please excuse my ignorance but xml really hurts my head and I have been struggling with this for a while.  Is there a way that I can either define the namespace prefix or handle this in some other more intelligent manner?

Thanks

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018326/lxml-iterparse-in-python-cant-handle-namespaces

Comment: I think lxml is expecting that the namespace is defined in the document see e.g. [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). If you have access to where the data is generated you can add the expected definition. Else you could strip the namespace away if you don't need it.

Comment: Thanks syntonym, how could I strip the namespace away?  

Interestingly (to me at least) If I change sphinx:docuemnt to sphinxdocument (which I don't really want to do for the sake of efficiency), it works fine but I can't run a replace on the gzip.open(filename.gz) output because I get:

xml=gzip.open('00000448069335828601.xml.gz')
xml.replace('sphinx:document','sphinxdocument')

AttributeError: 'GzipFile' object has no attribute 'replace'

Comment: Is that your entire XML document, or is that  snippet from in the middle of one?

Comment: @Rob, It's a snippet - the first few lines and the last line.  Each file is about 400 rows of xml, all in the same structure as the first few posted above.
thanks

Comment: Does the following string appear anywhere in your document: `xmlns:sphinx` ?

Comment: No, no mention of xmlns:sphinx Rob

Answer (score 2):

Your input file is not well formed XML. I assume that it is a snippet from a larger XML document.

Your choices are:

- Reconstruct the larger document. How you do this is specific to your application. You may have to consult with the people that created the file you are parsing.
- Parse the file in spite of its errors. To do that, use the `recover` keyword from `lxml.etree.iterparse`:

  ```
  xml2 =etree.iterparse(in_xml, recover=True)
  ```